# correct expression

Tags: tense

Which is the most correct and well sounding way to say that when someone is being calling me I'm being already fallen asleep

For example: (I wrote him)

> "I was asleep yesterday when you have called me"

but I think it is not correct

Answer (score 1):

The word "being" is wrongly used here. Usually you use "being" + adjective to describe something, eg.

1) You are being nasty.
2) He's being difficult here.

You do not actually use "being" with a verb.

Your sentence can be rephrased to:
1)I was asleep yesterday when you called me.
2) I had fallen asleep yesterday when you called me.

hope this helps.